# Get Context in Rest Call

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest

I'm pretty new to SharePoint Development.
The scenario is, I've got a list with dozens of columns. One of these columns gets rendered as button for every list item. When a user clicks the button, the corresponding list item should be duplicated.

The Button is rendered from a display template (JSLink) as follows:

```
 "<div class='Duplicator'><img src='[...].png'></div>"
```

For creating and reading a list item I use REST Calls as follows:

```
function getListItem(url, listname, id) {
    // Getting the list item
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + id + ")",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            printItems(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error getting item");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, I always have to give an ID as parameter and I don't find a way to automatically take the ID of the list item of the clicked button (like context in CSOM).

Anyone got an advice? Sorry for my bad English, seems like I am a bit out of practice...

Kind Regards,

Steve

Comment: This not REST related, You have a BUTTON in HTML and want to pass data to JavaScript. So what is your HTML?

Comment: @Danny '365CSI' Engelman
Hello, I forgot to mention, that I am rendering the list using display templates (JSLink). The button is rendered as follows: 

    "<div class='duplicator'><img src='[...].png'></div>" 


Did you mean this? Otherwise I don't think I have other HTML Code.

Comment: @SteveH can you please post the complete JSLink code

Comment: If you're using JSLink to render the link, then you should have access to the item id

Answer (score 1):

What about adding your ListItem Id to your onclick event in your jslink when you are rendering the button?

Answer (score 0):

> What about adding your ListItem Id to your onclick event in your jslink when you are rendering the button?

After all, that's what I did and it worked fine.

Thank you all :-)